# Why do some images not appear on android but on iphone?

Tags: android, titanium-mobile

I hope anyone can help me! I created an app for iPhone with Appcelerator Titanium, now I want to translate it for Android, but in the emulator some of my images do not appear and only with android 2.3.3 it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known and logged issue. It is scheduled to be fixed in the 1.6

You can check out the log from their bug tracking system:

[Medium Density Images Bug Logged - Appcelerator](https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/login)

So, no immediate relief for you but it's coming. This happens to be on occasion, I'm currently waiting for the UIscreen for iOS so I can support external displays / VGA dongle.